# Accessing vue mixin on vuex action

Tags: vue.js

I created vue mixin function that return the base url of the project. The reason I needed this mixin is because on the dev stage the value will come from configuration file, and on production stage it'll come from global variable `window`.

The `backEndHost` is accessible from any `.vue` file, but it's not accessible from vuex action.

#### Vue mixin declaration:

```
Vue.mixin({
    data: () => ({
        get backEndHost() {
            // ...
            return (isDev) devAddr : prodAddr
        }
    })
})
```

#### Vuex actions declaration:

```
const actions = {
    getChallengesData({ commit, state }, task) {
        // ...
        axios.get(this.backEndHost() + url).catch((thrown) => {
            swal('Error!', thrown.message, 'error')
        }).then((res) => {
            // ...
        })
    }
}
```

The `axios.get(this.backEndHost() + url)` triggered an error, saying that `this.backEndHost` is undefined.

> [Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: this.backEndHost is not a function"

Any idea how to resolve this error? or is there any workaround to achieve the same result?

Comment: You should put `backEndHost()` in `vuex` as a getter, or make it as utility helper (not mixins).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up putting the `backEndHost` into utility helper (thanks to @ittus). Since I still need the `backEndHost` to be available on all components, I also put it into mixin.

#### File: helper.js

```
export function backEndHost() {
    return (isDev) devAddr : prodAddr
}
```

#### File: main.js

```
import { backEndHost } from '@/utility/helper'

Vue.mixin({
    data: () => ({
        backEndHost
    })
})
```

#### File: actions.js

```
import { backEndHost } from '@/utility/helper'

const actions = {
    getChallengesData({ commit, state }, task) {
        // ...

        axios.get(backEndHost() + url).catch((thrown) => {
            swal('Error!', thrown.message, 'error')
        }).then((res) => {
            // ...
        })
    }
}
```